# Failed to install mongo db in Mac Big Sur

Tags: mongodb, macos, macos-big-sur

I am a newbie in `mongo db` and trying to install in my `Mac Big Sur OS`. It is a public beta OS. 
While install the `Mongo DB`, I am getting the below error:

```
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
NoMethodError: undefined method 'path' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean paths?
```

I have the latest Xcode installed. The steps I followed are from Official MongoDB [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) url.

Please help if there is a solution.

Comment: Try running `brew doctor`. That should tell you the error.

Comment: @HarshitRuwali, Thanks for the hint. The Xcode. was outdated. Installing the latest available version beta as the OS is also in beta.

Answer (score 1):

My case wasn't with installing MongoDB, but had the same problem when installing [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) using Homebrew.

After running `brew doctor`, my problem was with outdated Command Line Tools.

I followed the instruction shown in the error message.

However, the first solution didn't updated my command line tools.

```
$ softwareupdate --all --install --force
```

So I followed the second solution, and was able to install [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) successfully.

```
$ sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
$ sudo xcode-select --install
```